# Password reset token provider in ASP.NET core - IUserTokenProvider not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3, asp.net-core-webapi

Hello,

In order to getting password reset work I need to register an IUserTokenProvider instance into DI.

Without it I get exception at following line:

```cs
var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);
```

> ```cs
> "No IUserTokenProvider named 'PasswordResetTokenProvider' is registered."
> ```

That makes sense so I tried to register it in the DI:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IUserTokenProvider<User>, DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>>();
```

But the interface `IUserTokenProvider` does not exists. Do you know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's workaround or normal approach, but the `IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider` interface seems to be a right way. IUserTokenProvider appears to no longer exists.

Figured out that I have to register the provider manually in the identity:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
            {
                ...
                options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("Default", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<User>)));
            })
```

And the optional configuration in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.Name = "Default";
            o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        });
```

And the password reset / email validation tokens are working now.

PS: [Opened an issue for clarification](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1018)

Answer (score 26):

You can specify one of the built in providers;

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>{
        options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
    })
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Or create your own IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider and register it like so;

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => {
    options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = nameof(MyTokenProvider);
})
.AddTokenProvider<MyTokenProvider>(nameof(MyTokenProvider));
```

Comment: it takes me empty string instead of token

Answer (score 12):

add or correct following lines in startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

you can found more description [here](https://mattferderer.com/NotSupportedException-No-IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider-tuser-named-default-registered)

Answer (score 7):

You have to dig deep into the .NET Core code and find what internals the `AddIdentity` is doing.

What I found was the following that worked for us as we could not use `.AddIdentity()` as it overrode the IdentityServer4 middleware.

Instead, we added transients for the all the interfaces needed for UserManager and then used IdentityBuilder class to add the token provider.

**NOTE** The User class below inherits from `IdentityUser` as we needed to customize our user table.

```
// add User Manager related objects into DI configuration
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore<User, IdentityRole<string>, ApplicationDbContext>>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole<string>>, RoleStore<IdentityRole<string>, ApplicationDbContext>>();
services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<User>, PasswordHasher<User>>();
services.AddTransient<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
services.AddTransient<IdentityErrorDescriber>();
var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(typeof(User), typeof(IdentityRole<string>), services);
identityBuilder.AddTokenProvider("Default", typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>));
services.AddTransient<UserManager<User>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Add `.AddDefaultTokenProviders();` in ConfigureServices() method in startupclass**

```
 `in public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     services.AddIdentity<RegisterUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ContextClass>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ContextClass>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

It is AddIdentityCore version for only you add User, you might need it .