# No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'Default' is registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on an asp.net core mvc project (.net 5) but struggling hard with Identity related things.

I have a class `HedgehogUserAccount` that inherits from `IdentityUser` with two other classes that inherit from `HedgehogUserAccount`: `CustomerAccount` and `UserAccount` (bad choice of name, I know - I will change it when everything works). After a lot of work, I have managed to get the migrations to work and the program compiles and runs, but when I try to register a `User` I get the following error:

`NotSupportedException: No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'Default' is registered.`

The error comes from line 90 in my registration code (see full code pasted below - it is almost the same as the scaffolded registration page):

`var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);`

The relevant (I think) part of my Startup.cs looks like this:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<HedgehogUserAccount, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();

services.AddIdentityCore<UserAccount>(
        options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();

services.AddIdentityCore<CustomerAccount>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddDefaultUI();
```

I arrived at this code when trying to register my `UserManager` classes.

I have tried some variations of this (replacing the `AddDefaultTokenProviders`):

1. `.AddTokenProvider(TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider, typeof(EmailTokenProvider<UserAccount>))`
2. `.AddTokenProvider<EmailTokenProvider<UserAccount>>(TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider)`

But both of them yield the same error at the same point in my code. But I got an interesting message when I tried:

```cs
services.AddIdentityCore<UserAccount>(
      options => {
            options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("Default", new 
                  TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<UserAccount>)));
                 })
      .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
      .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
      .AddDefaultUI();
```

Then the error message I get is: `System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Default'` which feels a bit weird since the previous message said that no `Default` exists.

I guess what I must do is to provide my own `EmailTokenProvider` somehow? Or is there any other way? I would very much appreciate your help!

**Update**

I tried replace the line where the confirmation token is generated with the following line:

`var code = "testtoken";//await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);`

When I do this the program and the registration runs flawlessly! I guess this means that somehow the default token provider is not being registered correctly, but I am unsure how to proceed.

---

`Register.cshtml.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Hedgehog.Core.Application;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Hedgehog.UI.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<UserAccount> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<UserAccount> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<UserAccount> userManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            SignInManager<UserAccount> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new UserAccount { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User").Wait();

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password reset token provider in ASP.NET core - IUserTokenProvider not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445980/password-reset-token-provider-in-asp-net-core-iusertokenprovider-not-found)

Comment: Thank you @JeremyLakeman for your suggestion. Unfortunately I had already tried everything on that page. I also tried all suggestions on similar questions going back a few years :/

I eventually solved it by implementing my own token provider - not ideal perhaps, but it works as a charm. Thank you for taking interest in my problem!

Comment: I'm super stuck here. I have also tried everything posted on this page and it that link. Also tried my own token provider. Nothing works...
@AntimatterHedgehog can you post your solution please? I'm quite despered right now. Always getting the error: No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'Default' is registered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of headaches, I have now reached a conclusion to my problem. I solved it by implementing my own token provider and registering it with the system. In case anyone else crashes into the same wall as I did, I leave my solution here.

**Step 1: Implement IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider**

```cs
public class HedgehogEmailTwoFactorAuthentication<TUser> : IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : HedgehogUserAccount
    {
        public Task<bool> CanGenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
        {
            if (manager != null && user != null)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }

        // Genereates a simple token based on the user id, email and another string.
        private string GenerateToken(HedgehogUserAccount user, string purpose)
        {
            string secretString = "coffeIsGood";
            return secretString + user.Email + purpose + user.Id;
        }

        public Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(GenerateToken(user, purpose));
        }

        public Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string token, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(token == GenerateToken(user, purpose));
        }
    }
```

**Step 2: Register your new and shiny token provider in services**

```cs
services.AddIdentityCore<CustomerAccount>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddTokenProvider("Default", typeof(HedgehogEmailTwoFactorAuthentication<CustomerAccount>))
                    .AddDefaultUI();
```

**Step 3: Register with DI container**

In ConfigureContainer (I'm using Autofac):

```cs
builder.RegisterType<HedgehogEmailTwoFactorAuthentication<CustomerAccount>>()
                    .As<IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<CustomerAccount>>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

If you are not using Autofac, you need to call `AddScoped` instead of `InstancePerLifetimeScope` (assuming this is the correct lifetime for a token generator).

Also, you might want to use a better token generator for your implementation :)

Reference: [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iusertwofactortokenprovider-1.generateasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider_1_GenerateAsync_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager__0___0_)

Comment: Twenty minutes after asking, you edited your question to (sort of) read *`/*await*/ _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);` When I do this the program and the registration runs flawlessly!* - still there 2022/08/28.

Comment: what does if need to generate 4 digits number and validate it as well then do we need to store in the DB in separate table or is there any way that identity stores itself?

Answer (score 6):

The solution that works for me is:
Add `.AddDefaultTokenProviders();` only to one of your IdentityDbContext, then on the other 2, Create a custom UserManager that inherits from UserManage then in the constructor add the following line

```
RegisterTokenProvider(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, new EmailTokenProvider<Owner>());
```

this line registers a new EmailTokenProvider for the UserManager.