# Multiple Identities Asp net core 7 evolves into a 6 character EmailConfirmationToken instead of long standard string

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Hi to implement multiple identities in asp net core 7 i learned here [No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'Default' is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361087/no-iusertwofactortokenprovidertuser-named-default-is-registered) that i would only need one Identity with AddDefaultTokenProviders and 2 Identities without like

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<Care, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<CareGiver>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MContext>().AddUserManager<CareGiverManager>();
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<CareUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MContext>().AddUserManager<CareUserManager>();
```

and that i should inherit the userManager class twice like

```
using latest.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace latest.Security;

public class CareGiverManager : UserManager<CareGiver> {
    public CareGiverManager(
        IUserStore<CareGiver> store, 
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
        IPasswordHasher<CareGiver> passwordHasher, 
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<CareGiver>> userValidators, 
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<CareGiver>> passwordValidators, 
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, 
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, 
        IServiceProvider services, 
        ILogger<UserManager<CareGiver>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger) {
        RegisterTokenProvider(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, new EmailTokenProvider<CareGiver>(),);
        // RegisterTokenProvider<CareGiver>(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, new EmailTokenProvider<CareGiver>());
    }

}
public class CareUserManager : UserManager<CareUser> {
    public CareUserManager(
        IUserStore<CareUser> store, 
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, 
        IPasswordHasher<CareUser> passwordHasher, 
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<CareUser>> userValidators, 
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<CareUser>> passwordValidators, 
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, 
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, 
        IServiceProvider services, 
        ILogger<UserManager<CareUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger) {
        RegisterTokenProvider(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, new EmailTokenProvider<CareUser>());
    }
}
```

Now does userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync() work but it creates a 6 digit token instead of the usual long string
Does anyone know how to achieve this long string with multiple identities?

Comment: Please share complete sample code(pls hide sensitive info)? With the existing code, your problem cannot be reproduced.